# iPhone - PushMeBaby example error

Tags: iphone

im having an error while running the PushMeBaby examples as followed in this tutorial for push notifications http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

In the console the error message is

```
connect returned error
```

```
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] MakeServerConnection(): -36
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] SSLNewContext(): 0
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] SSLSetIOFuncs(): 0
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] SSLSetConnection(): 0
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] SSLSetPeerDomainName(): 0
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] SecKeychainOpen(): 0
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] SecCertificateCreateFromData(): 0
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate(): 0
 PushMeBaby[708:a0f] SSLSetCertificate(): 0

\274\270LN\247\373?\276a\216\222\376\216\367\262p\332\302 \2342\3713\301_ZV\344'sV\300

\300   \300\300\300\300\300\300\300\300\300\300\300\300\300

 \300

/5

 23894:9#!gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
```

Everytime i build and run it, the string of numbers seems to change.

I have checked the device token, and i have the aps_developer_identity.cer

Has anyone successfully got this thing working?

Comment: hmm i found out that my network gateway port 2195 , port 30 is blocked. does it needs to be opened?

Answer (score 4):

I use pushMeBaby and the main gotcha I've found is;

Does the computer you are testing on have the correct .cer and .p12 in the keychain? This is **in addition** to having the correct .cer bundled with the pushMeBaby app itself. You know if you have it right if, when launching pushMeBaby, it asks permission to access a certificate in your keychain. If it's not asking permission, it's because you don't have it (unless you do have it and granted access ALWAYS of course).

I bashed my head against the wall for ages with that one. Does that help at all?